# Control Emulator from Phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

If I connect my phone to my PC with the USB connector can I use the phone as an input device for the emulator?

What I really want is to test the application on my phone and have that reflected on my PC and/or in the emulator.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to have the emulator reflect your phone if you actually have your phone to test on? Screenshot purposes or something else?

Comment: Not the 100% what you want, but this http://experitest.com/ tool will create a copy of your phone as emulator on monitor, so that you can control it from phone or from emulator you can work on phone. P.S. it allows remote cloud connection too.

Comment: I want to broadcast my device on a PC while debugging

Comment: There as no solution for this, but I was able to accomplish the goal using Bomgar